# R Subset area NetCDF

Tags: r, subset, netcdf

I'm having trouble trying to read a plus 2Gb NetCDF file from [links](https://cds.climate.copernicus.eu/cdsapp#!/dataset/satellite-land-cover?tab=overview) in R

If I try to read the whole file R returns me a message that I don't have enough memory,

```
'Error: cannot allocate vector of size 31.3 Gb'
```

as it was reported by the post [link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/360225/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-a-netcdf-in-r)

Following the this post advice, I decided to read only the part of the file based on the geographic coordinates of the a given area. Here is my code:

```
#load any packages

library(ncdf4)
```

set path and filename

```
ncpath <- "C:\Users\Me\Documents\Science\GIS\Global Land Cover\"

ncname <- "C3S-LC-L4-LCCS-Map-300m-P1Y-2018-v2.1.1"

ncfname <- paste(ncpath, ncname, ".nc", sep="") 

dname <-"lccs_class"
```

open a netCDF file

```
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname) 

print(ncin)
```

get longitude and latitude

```
lon <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lon")

nlon <- dim(lon)

head(lon)

lat <- ncvar_get(ncin,"lat")

nlat <- dim(lat) head(lat)

print(c(nlon,nlat))

#' create a bounding box to work with a subset 
LonIdx <- c(841, 842, 844,845,846,847,848)

LatIdx <- c(93,94,95,96)
```

However, when I try to execute the code for the Subset:

```
Susbset <- ncvar_get(ncin, dname,
                start = c(LatIdx[1], LonIdx[1]),
                count = c(length(LatIdx),length(LonIdx)))
```

I get the error:

```
> Error in ncvar_get_inner(ncid2use, varid2use, nc$var[[li]]$missval,
> addOffset, : Error: variable has 3 dims, but start has 2 entries. They
> must match!
```

Can anyone help me? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like there is still a third dimension to specify before you can procceed.
Let's suppose it is a time variable:

```
start = c(LatIdx[1], LonIdx[1], DesiredTimeIdx), 
count = c(length(LatIdx),length(LonIdx), 1))
```

This should read all lats an all lons in that specific time.